# C# application using a Local database with stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I am trying to develop a simple C# application which use a database. I am currently using **MS Server 2008**, but I found a portability issue since running the application on different computers would require MS Server to be installed. Also, my database makes use of stored procedures.

What other database types I can use in order to overcome this problem (n.b. it must use stored procedures)?

If I am to use MS Server 2008, assuming it is installed on every pc, how can I copy my .mdf file in order to be accessible? (i.e. install it on application load ?)

UPDATE

From [this website](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008), I found the following connection string :

Attach a database file on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance ...

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\asd\qwe\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

I presume that this will copy the .mdf file from my folder.
Hence, I am using the following connection string but to no success ...

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=...... database path.... ;Database=TrieDB.mdf; Trusted_Connection=Yes;

Directory lookup for the file "... database path... " failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Cannot attach the file '... database path...' as database 'TrieDB.mdf'
```

Comment: Why don't you have your application connect to a centralized sql server rather than install sql server on every workstation?

Comment: Why do you need stored procedures for local databases?  Just curious - this doesn't sound like a favorable design.

Comment: Alternatively, how critical - how *genuinely* critical - is the use of stored procedures to the application - I appreciate that you have them now. Additionally is this multi-user software or a single user per app instance?

Comment: First of all thanks for your replies.. @SeanBarlow .. i was thinking of doing that but i need speed in my database since this is a 'look-up' table for a suffix trie..

Comment: @tsells thanks for your reply mate.. as i said to Sean Barlow, I need this database for speed and using stored procedures will boost up my performance...

Comment: @Murph .. this is a single user application.. basically its a suffix trie where indexed words are stored in this database and searched when required.. will serve as a sort of look up table.. thanks for you reply :)

Comment: I have found that compiled queries using Entity Framework can be as fast as stored procedures. You may want to look into EF without stored procedures. Also have you looked at options other than a relation database for storage?

Answer (score 1):

Most "certified" database engines requires you to actually install the engine.
Most "certified" database engines enable the use of stored procedures.

In order to have the .mdf file on more machines you can simply copy it and afterwards use the sql management studio to attach the file to the engine, but that is not an ideal solution if you planning to distribute your application in many places, the ideal solution will be to create an installation package and fix that it is automaticlly being done from the installation and undone when you uninstall.

*imho: You insist on stored procedure with a de-centeralized solution - do notice that this is a rather rare tactic - it has the smell of a wrong path..
But I can't be sure unless you provide some more information.*

Comment: The aim of the application is as a Suffix trie, where documents are indexed in the database and searched when required. In order to boost performance and avoid creating countless of connections for each letter to be indexed (or searched), I opted to use stored procedures and reduce the number of connections (i.e. increasing performance)..

Comment: Ok, I share your grief :) 
I can understand why you need many databases but not why you need the stored procedures. I don't think it will matter if you open a connection that call STP or execute a dynamiclly created sql script that do somthing. in both cases you use the same amount of connections. the benefit of not using STP is probably clear to you so i'll skip it, entity framework can really make your life easier by bringing you the power of your sql needs right down to the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are really two general designs to do something like what you're describing.  Either have a centralized database that all copies of the application (and/or multiple applications) access, or create an installation package complete with the database (which is generally only accessed by a single application).

Personally, if you don't want to, or can't, use a centralized database solution, I would suggest changing your philosophy about stored procedures and looking into [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876).  I found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/02/11/stored-procedures-and-sql-server-compact-the-great-debate.aspx) discussing the reasons why SQL Server Compact doesn't have sprocs, which I think will be useful to you, even if you decide you really need them.

That said, if you need to install a database with your app, you can create a [setup package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx) within Visual Studio, of you could also look into using [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: thanks for your reply and suggestions.. Originally i was using MS SQL CE but as you mentioned they don't use sprocs.. due to the maximum speed required, then i opted to MS SQL Server with sprocs, and the speed gained was drastically :/ I'll keep the setup package method as an alternative if no solution is found.. thanks a lot for your suggestions .

Comment: @user1317277, I'm guessing you're seeing more performance gain from a fully installed rdbms than from sprocs... but either way, the easiest method to get everything you need setup, from the user's perspective, is with some form of installation package. I don't think you're going to get away from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can detach the database, copy over and attach the mdf file on the destination database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate.. and ideas how I can implement this ? something to do with the connection string ?